# arbitrage opportunity and maximizing the function

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let's say you have currencies,`A, B, C`

with the exchanges rates  `a/b, b/c, c/a`

If the product

```
a/b * b/c * c/a > 1
```

then the arbitrage opportunity exists. And larger that product is, more profit you can make.

So essentially i would like to maximize the function y

```
y = a/b * b/c * c/a
```

where `a/b, b/c, c/a` change on minute by minute basis which can be updated from the exchange API.

The problem is that there are many many currency triples to consider and not really sure how to approach picking the right combination.

it seems like there should be a way to set up an excel sheet. anyone have any thought?

Here's an example of an excel sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BK0sJf91Niqbodao_Ipf7RCvNTRrH9UI-KUaKQJgjZ0/edit#gid=0

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The given product is always 1.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. yes, the product should always be 1 mathematically. but it is not in the market let it be forex or cryptocurrency. take a look at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BK0sJf91Niqbodao_Ipf7RCvNTRrH9UI-KUaKQJgjZ0/edit#gid=0

Comment: It's unclear what the question is. (1) How is an API related here? (2) You only show A, B, and C. There is only 1 "triple".

Comment: Ok. I'm on binance for cryptocurrency. They have over 1000 alt coins listed. i've added an excel sheet to the post.